# Using Image.fromarray() settings values to zero

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

this is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
a = np.full((400, 400, 3), 255)
print(a)
im = Image.fromarray(a, mode="RGB")
im.show()
```

when I run this I get this image:

[image: verticle lines of alternating colours]

I've looked around online and I can't find an answer to my question.
If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I see you answered your own question which is great! However one thing that caught my attention is that you said "I can't find an answer to my question", but I can't seem to find any questions in this thread, or in that case any question marks... So next time please also describe your desired output! Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert/set the values to the type np.uint8

so instead of:

`a = np.full((400, 400, 3), 255)`

you should do:

`a = np.full((400, 400, 3), 255, dtype=np.uint8)`